# INSERT INTO return Error 1364 - Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: javascript, php, sql

mySQL WARNING!
DB Error: mySQL Error on Query :

```
INSERT INTO ` LOG` (`user_id`, `ip`, `created`, `type`, `message`,
                    `info_icon`, `importance`) 
VALUES ('admin', '112.134.33.142', NOW(), 
        'user','User admin has successfully logged out.','user', 'no');
```

More Information:

```
Mysql Error : 1364
Mysql Error no # : Field 'failed' doesn't have a default value
Date : May 25, 2016, 8:20 pm
Referer: 1
Script: /logout.php
```

Comment: You need to provide a value for the `failed` column, or update your table to allow either a default/null value

Comment: INSERT INTO log (user_id, ip, created, type, message, info_icon, importance,failed) VALUES ('admin', '112.134.33.142', NOW(), 'user', 'User admin has successfully logged out.', 'user', 'no',current_date());

Comment: Also, you should to provide more detail at title.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed one field -> `failed` in your insert query. Add that field and value for it.

Example : 
INSERT INTO `LOG` (`user_id`, `ip`, `created`, `type`, `message`,
 `info_icon`, `importance`, `failed`) VALUES
                  ('admin', '112.134.33.142', NOW(), 
                   'user','User admin has successfully logged out.','user', 'no', 'your failed value');